# There exist Sylow $p$-subgroups $P,R$ of $G$ s.t. $[P:P\cap R]=[R:P\cap R]=p$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Given $p$ is prime, and $|G|<\infty$, let $n_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$.

Suppose $n_p\not\equiv 1$ mod $p^2$. Then there exist Sylow $p$-subgroups $P,R$ of $G$ s.t. $[P:P\cap R]=[R:P\cap R]=p$.

My attempt: Since $n_p\not\equiv 1$ mod $p^2$, $n_p\not=1$, we have two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups $P,R$.

Since $P\cap R\leq P,R$, if $|P|=|R|=p^n$, we have $|P\cap R|=1,p,p^2,...,p^{n-1}$. ($|P\cap R|\not=p^n$ since $P\not=R$.) We need to show $|P\cap R|=p^{n-1}$.

Let $|G|=p^n m$ where $p\not|\ m$. Then $|G|\geq |PR|=\frac{|P||R|}{|P\cap R|}=\frac{p^n\cdot p^n}{|P\cap R|}.$ So $|P\cap R|\geq p^n/m$. So if $m<p^n$, and then $|P\cap R|>1$. But we don't know whether $m<p^n$ is true.

So basically I want to eliminate all cases of $|P\cap R|=1,p,...,p^{n-2}$, but I'm stuck from the very beginning. How can I go further from here?

Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366866/there-exist-sylow-subgroups-p-and-q-for-which-pp-cap-q-q-p-cap-q?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511736/show-that-there-exists-two-sylow-p-subgroups-p-and-q-such-that-pp-cap-q?rq=1

Comment: @Desiato Thank you, they helped me a lot.