# Group of order $1053$ is not simple

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

$1053=3^4\cdot 13$. By Sylow theory, we have $n_3=1,13$, and $n_{13}=1,27$.($n_i$ means the number of the Sylow $i$-subgroups in $G$)

If $n_3=1$ or $n_{13}=1$, then there is a unique Sylow subgroup, which is normal in $G$.

So let's assume $n_3=13$ and $n_{13}=27$. If Sylow $3$-subgroups intersect trivially, then we have $|G|\geq 13\cdot 80+27\cdot 12+1=1040+324+1>1053$, which is a contradiction.(Sylow $13$-subgroups intersect trivially, since the order of them are a prime, $13$)

Now assume that the Sylow $3$-subgroups intersect nontrivially. That is, if $P,Q\in Syl_3(G)$, then $|P\cap Q|=3, 3^2,3^3$.($|P\cap Q|\not= 3^4$ since $n_3\not=1$) And since $n_3=13\not \equiv 1$ (mod $3^2$), $|P\cap Q|=3^3=27$ by the fact: [$n_p\not\equiv 1$ (mod $p^2$) $\implies$ $\exists P,Q$ Sylow $p$-subgroups s.t. $[P:P\cap Q]=[Q:P\cap Q]=p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337459/there-exist-sylow-p-subgroups-p-r-of-g-s-t-pp-cap-r-rp-cap-r-p).

And I don't know what to do from here. I observed $|G/P\cap Q|=3\cdot 13=39$, but $G/P\cap Q$ is not cyclic in general, so it didn't much help.

Comment: The normalizer of $P \cap Q$ contains both $P$ and $Q$, so it must be the whole group.

Comment: How do you know that $P,Q\leq N_G(P\cap Q)$?

Comment: Any subgroup of index $p$ in a $p$-group is normal. So $P \cap Q $ is normal in both $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $P, Q \subset N_{G}(P\cap Q)$.So, $|PQ| \leq |N_{G}(P\cap Q)|$. Now what can be $|PQ|$?

$|PQ|= \frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}$.

Let $|P\cap Q|=3$,then $|PQ|=3^{7}$ which exceeds the order of the group and is not possible.

Let $|P\cap Q|=3^{2}$,then $|PQ|=3^{6}$. But then what can be the order of $N_{G}(P\cap Q)$? The only possibility is $|N_{G}(P\cap Q)=3^{4}. 13$. Hence $P\cap Q$ is normal in $G$ and we are done.

Let Let $|P\cap Q|=3^{3}$,then $|PQ|=3^{5}$ . Hence the choices for $|N_{G}(P\cap Q)$ are $3^{3}.13$ , $1053$. For the latter case again $P\cap Q$ is normal.

But if $|N_{G}(P\cap Q)|=3^{3}.13$, we have $[G:N_{G}(P\cap Q)]=3$. Since $1053$ doesnot divide $3!$, By index theorem we conclude that $G$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup.

Hence all the cases has been exhausted and we conclude $G$ is not simple.